# Existence of free operators, independent and with given distributions

Tags: probability-theory, noncommutative-geometry

I am trying to learn free probability from scratch, mostly by myself. I am trying to prove the following result.

> If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are compactly supported probability measures, then
>   there exists a $C^*$ probability space $(\mathcal{A}, \phi)$ and self
>   adjoint $a,~b\in \mathcal{A}$ which are free independent and have
>   distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively.

I was told that this can be easily proved using free products of $*$-probability spaces. But I can not see how it follows. Can someone give me a line of proof, or point out some place where I can get the result? Advanced thanks for any helps/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the spectral theorem, for each bounded self-adjoint element $a$ of a non-commutative probability space $(\mathcal{A},\tau)$  ,there exists a unique Borel probability measure $\mu_{a}$ on $Spec(a)$ (known as the spectral measure of $a$) such that $\tau(P (a)) = \int_{\mathbb{C}} P (z) d\mu_{a}(z)$ holds for all polynomials $P : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

One can consider the free product of the  unital $c^{\ast}$-algebra generated by $a$ and the unital $c^{\ast}$-algebra generated by $b$.